# HBase looks for hadoop-common library on HDFS

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I am trying to run a hadoop(version:2.2.0) job on a single machine which writes the reducer output into a Hbase(version 0.98) table. When I run the job, HBase looks for hadoop-common.jar file in the HDFS:

> 2014-03-07 10:52:44,499 ERROR [main] security.UserGroupInformation
>   (UserGroupInformation.java:doAs(1494)) - PriviledgedActionException
>   as:ubuntu (auth:SIMPLE) cause:java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does
>   not exist:
>   hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000/home/ubuntu/workspace/XXXX/lib/hadoop-common-2.2.0.jar

Here is my job configuration:

```
Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "127.0.0.1");
Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "CreateLookUpTable");
job.setJarByClass(HBaseLookUp.class);
// configure output and input source
N3TextInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(inputText));
job.setInputFormatClass(N3InputFormat.class);
// configure mapper and reducer
job.setMapperClass(HBaseLookUp.Map.class);
// configure output
TableMapReduceUtil.initTableReducerJob("LookUp", HBaseLookUp.Red.class, job);
job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
job.setReducerClass(HBaseLookUp.Red.class);

job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(NullWritable.class);
```

Any idea about this issue?

Comment: can you tell, how you run your job - is it run as a jar, remote/locally please specify.

Comment: As I mentioned, it is on a single machine(Locally). I tried to run it from eclipse and also as a single jar file by hadoop jar command. Same error in both cases.

Comment: @Reza, have you found a solution for this problem?

Comment: I had similar problem. Try this [post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28877600/why-do-i-need-to-keep-hbase-lib-folder-in-hdfs/29121662#29121662